# How can I make the label in the same line as `<h3>` or `<div>` or,,,

Tags: html, css, styles

How can I make the label in the same line as `<h3>` or `<div>` or,,,

`<h3 style="display: inline-block"> Reply to <label id="test">test</label></h3>`

PS:It may merit consideration that my label in inside of `<h3>`

Thanks

Comment: I already tried but the result is not in the same line!

Comment: It works OK for me in a fiddle with simply: `<h3>Reply to <label id="test">test</label></h3>`

Comment: [It seems on the same line here](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/ErEkn/).

Comment: YEa now I tried in a simple page and and it is working for me too! but not in my project! Ok I will try to figure it out thanks :)

Comment: inline and inline-block are *not* the same

Comment: I tried both; it seems Twitter Bootstrap adds block display for  labels. Do you know how to disable it?

Comment: I solved my problem with Span, but it is interesting to knwo if there is any way to disable the block display for labeles which is set by bootstrap. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the `label` element has inline display, so your code snippet should work fine.  Are you including some other CSS file?  Or perhaps a CSS reset like Twitter Bootstrap?  Many CSS resets declare block display for `label` elements.

Comment: Yes Im using Twitter Bootstrap

Comment: Just add your own style for `label` and set `display: inline`.  Once that's done, make sure your new CSS is being included AFTER Twitter Bootstrap so that your new rule overwrites the TB one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem with the label when I run the HTML in jsFiddle.

You can use the `vertical-align` property.

```
vertical-align:baseline;
```